# Any ideas to make my code efficient for looping 10 000 000 000 times

Tags: java

I've made a simple code to count the occurrences of the digit '14' from a given number. I've successfully print out the counter if the given number is 10 000 000 and it took less than 1 second. When i increase the number to 
10 000 000 000 it took 459 seconds. Any ideas on how to make it runs faster?

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long counter = 0L;
        for (long i = 14; i <= 10000000000L; i++)
        {
            String s = Long.toString(i);//i.ToString();
            if (s.contains("14"))
            {
                counter += 1;
            }

        }
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        long convert = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(totalTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        System.out.println(convert + " seconds");
        System.out.println(counter);
```

time taken : 459 seconds 
number of 14 appears : 872348501

Comment: what i mean by the occurrences of '14' is as follow:  there are 20 numbers that contain 14 between 1 to 1,000.
(14, 114, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 214, 314, 414, 514, 614, 714, 814, 914)

Comment: Simple don't count but instead generate all the possible cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious optimization: don't construct strings.

Just check the last two digits of the number, and then divide by 10 until you find a 14:

```
boolean matches = false;
for (long num = i; num >= 14 && !matches; num /= 10) {
  matches = (num % 100) == 14;
}
if (matches) {
  counter += 1;
}
```

But, you would likely just be able to calculate the number of cases, using the inclusion/exclusion principle.

Comment: I don't like reading that for-loop. Why not `if(matches) {counter++; break;}`?

Comment: tried your code mate, its a lot faster than my code but still took 192 seconds. Is it possible to make it less than 1 sec?

Comment: @KevinHelma yes. But I'm guessing this is some sort of coding challenge, so where would be the fun for you if you just got the answer :) Hint, use memoization.

Comment: Less than 1 second is not possible. Just an empty loop with the numbers you supply takes over 6 seconds on my decent laptop. Even if the processor was able to execute one iteration of the loop per clock tick (which I don't think it can), you would need a 10 GHz processor just to get the looping itself under 1 second.

Comment: @Tobb it's not possible with this algorithm. It's possible, though.

Comment: AH ok so basically need to change my algorithm. Got it

Comment: If you have to loop through 10 billion iterations, this alone will take more than 1 second with a typical computer today, unless you multithread and use more than one processor core.

Comment: But my comment isn't that much a statement of what is physically possible, but rather what the expectations should be.

Comment: @Tobb but if you change the algorithm so you don't do 10 billion iterations, you don't need to do 10 billion iterations. I never said *what* to memoize.

Comment: The question is about looping 10 billion iterations. Which is practically impossible in under 1 second.

Comment: @Tobb the question is about "count[ing] the occurrences of the digit '14' from a given number".

Comment: That is the problem to solve, not the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve performance by combining the solution proposed by Andy Turner and java8 parallel streams:

```
private boolean twoDigitExist(long x, long d) 
    { 
        while (x >= d) 
        { 
            if (x % 100 == d) 
                return true;
            x /= 10; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

And the loop could be parallelized as:

```
long counter = LongStream.range(14, 10000000000L).parallel().filter(l->twoDigitExist(l, 14)).count();
```

Comment: thx mate, tried it with your way it shortened into 66 seconds